# How Do I Use Spring Data HBase With Annotation Driven Config

Tags: spring, hadoop, hbase, spring-data

I am interested in Spring Data and HBase.  I included this jar in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I see [some references](http://static.springsource.org/spring-hadoop/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/hbase.html) about using the HbaseTemplate class.

These examples all have XML based Spring HBase configuration.  I am using Annotation base config,

```
 // default HBase configuration
<hdp:hbase-configuration/>

// wire hbase configuration (using default name 'hbaseConfiguration') into the template 
<bean id="htemplate" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate" p:configuration-ref="hbaseConfiguration"/>
```

How do I do this from annotation such as:

```
@Bean
@Named("hbaseTemplate")
public HbaseTemplate hbaseTemplate() {
    return new HbaseTemplate();
}
```

I tried that approach but it failed.

Answer (score 2):

```
// <hdp:hbase-configuration/>
@Bean
public Configuration configuration() {
    return HBaseConfiguration.create();
}

// <bean id="htemplate" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate" p:configuration-ref="hbaseConfiguration"/>
@Bean(name = "hbaseTemplate")
public HbaseTemplate hbaseTemplate() {
    return new HbaseTemplate(configuration());
}
```